# Can't access variable through require

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I try to access the 'app' variable from the required index.js though my test, my test code can't resolve the variable 'app'.

**server.js**

```
'use strict';

var supertestKoa = require('supertest-koa-agent');

var app = module.exports = require('koa')(),
    port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

supertestKoa(app);

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Koa app is listening on port' + port);
});
```

**myTest.js**

```
'use strict';
var api = require('../../server.js');

var port = 3000;
var request = require('co-supertest').agent(api.app.listen(port, console.log('test app running' + port)));
```

it complains that it's not aware of 'app' in the agent(api.**app**....)

the 'api' does resolve.  Just not api.**app**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `server.js` you export `var app = require('koa')()`. In `myTest.js`, you require `server.js` as `api`. That means `api` now equals `app`.

Drop `.app` and instead use:

```
var request = require('co-supertest')
    .agent(api.listen(port, console.log('test app running' + port)));
```

<sup>Note how it's `app.listen` instead of `app.api.listen`.</sup>